# Find the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt[3]{2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt[3]{2}$

I understand the solution as far as finding a basis, seeing how it acts by left multiplication on $\sqrt[3]{2}$, finding a matrix, finding the eigenvalues, and getting the polynomial that way.

What I don't understnad is what my basis should be. Should $\{1,\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{4}\}$ be a basis because they are powers of $\sqrt[n]{2}$ for $n=0,1,2$?

Comment: Although in general getting the minimal polynomial the way you propose works, in this case (and nearly every case you do by hand) it is much easier to 'see' a polynomial that has $\sqrt[3]{2}$ as a root and prove that it is irreducible.

Comment: That is a basis; they are $n$th powers of $\sqrt[3]2\,$ for $n=0,1,2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you have to find the minimal polynomial on $\mathbb{Q}$. Let us put $\zeta=\sqrt[3]2$, then you have that $X^3-2$ has $\zeta$ as root, moreover it is irreducible by Eisenstein criterion, so it is the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$.